# expression not supported in MongoDB update definition

Tags: c#, mongodb, expression, mongodb-.net-driver, findoneandupdate

I have a find one and update kind of method in c# for mongodb which gets a collection string

```
IMongoCollection<TDocument> col = _database.GetCollection<TDocument>(collection);

UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>()
                .Set(doc => doc.Session, session);

TDocument? doc = col.FindOneAndUpdate(doc => doc.Field == TempFunction("sometext", doc.AnotherField), update)
```

**Both "Field" and "AnotherField" are string fields of a generic TDocument**
I suppose the update definition is not important here since the error is related to the expression filter, in particular the first argument of "FindOneAndUpdate" is of type Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>>, the TempFunction method is an example of whenever the findone method throws an error

```
public static string TempFunction(string text1, string text2)
    {
        return text1 + text2;
    }
```

In particular the error that the main method throws is

" An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not supported: TempFunction("123456789", doc.Email)."

But of course by replacing the "TempFunction" implementation in the third line fixes the error

```
TDocument? doc = col.FindOneAndUpdate(doc => doc.Field == "sometext" + doc.AnotherField, update)
```

Comment: How is the MongoDB driver supposed to take your `TempFunction`, which is written in C#, and translate it into a query which MongoDB can execute?

Comment: @canton7 I don't know and is why I'm asking this, in my case thought the TempFunction is quite complicated so here I just gave a simpler example.

Comment: The answer is that it can't. Your query is run by the database, so it needs to be something which can be translated into MongoDB's query language (MongoDB is not able to execute compiled C# when running a query). That means that it needs to be a linq expression (and not a call to a method which is compiled C# code), and it needs to only do things which are supported by the MongoDB query language

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, I guess MongoDB .net driver has no way to let this happen if passed to the update filter?